# How do I select the parent node from a child node?

Tags: jquery

I'm wrote some jquery code to get the click event on the `div` inside another `div` like this.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="values_to_get">
    <div class="catch_click_event_here">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So now can someone help me please, I need to get values in the div with `class="values_to_get"` when I click on the `div` with `class="catch_click_event_here"`. I have a list of `divs` with `class="parent"`

Comment: Just a tip. If you want to type code in your question (or answer), you should highlight it and click the "Code Sample" formatting button--it's the one with "101 010" on it. That allows you to type normal html brackets.

Comment: thank Calvin alot before that I took me a lot of time to write out my code

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div.catch_click').click(function (){
    variable = $(this).parent().attr('value');  //this is div.catch_click
});
```

In that way, you get the content of the 'value' attribute in the "values to get" div.
Don't know what values you need, but just replace 'value' with the attribute you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you using jquery 1.3 or greater you can use the [`closest`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) method

```
$('.catch_click_event_here').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.values_to_get').val();
});
```